# Ad-hoc promise library

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

When using Angular, I typically used JQuery's `$.Deferred` object for creating promises on-the-fly. Apart from actual HTTP requests, it's great for returning arbitrary mock data within a promise:

```
getMockData: function() {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   deferred.resolve({mockData: 'foo-bar'});
   return deferred.promise();
}
```

Pretty simple. That said, I'm using Aurelia these days, which isn't tied into JQuery (or jqLite) as Angular is. As such, I lose `$.Deferred()`. Is there a comparable library that would provide the same functionality as `$.Deferred()`?

Otherwise, is it considered inappropriate or bad practice to just install JQuery and use `$.Deferred()` when necessary? I suspect it will only be temporary, but perhaps not. I'm not opposed to JQuery, but obviously don't want to import it just to obtain a single module.

Aurelia Example:

```
import {DataService} from './data-service';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(DataService)
export class PatientService {

  constructor(dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService;
  }

  getPatients(url, emr) {
   // Server incomplete, so comment out the real call (for now)
   // return this.dataService.get(url + '/patients?emr=' + emr);

   [generate and return a promise here. Cool to just use $.Deferred()?]

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, using jQuery `$.Deferred` promises is considered inappropriate. Especially when you have better alternatives available, such as Angular `$q` promises or an ES6 polyfill.

Comment: Thanks, it did have a smell, hence my hesitation. Total bonehead move on my part however, as estes points out, I'm able to easily solve this problem with pure JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  getPatients(url, emr) {
   // Server incomplete, so comment out the real call (for now)
   // return this.dataService.get(url + '/patients?emr=' + emr);

   return new Promise((resolve) => resolve({mockData: 'foo-bar'}));
   // or
   // return Promise.resolve({mockData: 'foo-bar'});
  }
```

The one should not back to Deferred (anti)pattern outside jQuery scope, once proper promise implementations are already there.

`dataService` can do mocking internally if it is required on constant basis.

Comment: Pure JS. This is what I was looking for, I guess I always think to use some 3rd party wrapper, but this is much more elegant.

Comment: Even more elegant, and by far better: `return Promise.resolve({mockData: 'foo-bar'});`

Comment: Yes, it looks even better. @lux Since you have Angular background, this may look familiar to you, it would be `return $q((resolve) => resolve(...))` or `return $q.resolve(...)` there (Deferred API is also there for historical reasons too but the one is not obliged to use it).